# Load all content of a webpage without having to scroll down

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, internet, scrolling

Recently many websites have adopted load on scroll approach. One has to scroll down to load more content for EG: youtube,google,facebook. Is there a way one can load all content without having to scroll?